# D3 hide unlinked nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to hide all unlinked nodes, I do not want to delete them totally. Mainly because I want to add those later on, if links exist. I just want to receive all nodes which are not linked yet. My attempt was to create another dataset and loop through each node.id and simply compare those node.id with the link.target and link.source.

If true I push the related node into data.nodes which I actually use for the graph. Unfortunately it seems there is an error with the index. As I gain 4 instead of expected 3 nodes.

I assume there is a embedded D3 trick which I do not know yet or of course better attempt.

```js
        var width = window.innerWidth,
            height = window.innerHeight;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        ////////////////////////
        // outer force layout
        
        var unfilteredData = {
            "nodes": [{
                "id": "A",
            },
            {
                "id": "B",
            },
            {
                "id": "C",
            },
            {
                "id": "D",
            },
            {
                "id": "E",
            }],
            "links": [{
                "source": "A",
                "target": "B"
            },
            {
                "source": "B",
                "target": "C"
            },
            {
                "source": "C",
                "target": "A"
            }]
        }

        let data = {
            "nodes":[{}],
            "links":[{}],
        }

        data.links = unfilteredData.links

        for (let i = 0; i < unfilteredData.nodes.length; i++) {
            unfilteredData.links.forEach( function(li) {
                if (unfilteredData.nodes[i].id == li.source || unfilteredData.nodes[i].id == li.target ) {
                    data.nodes.push(unfilteredData.nodes[i])
                    i = i+1
                }
            })
        }

      

        console.table(data.nodes)

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id
            }).distance(250))

        linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkscontainer")
        nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")


        links = linksContainer.selectAll(".path")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "path")
            .attr("fill", "transparent")

        nodes = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
            .data(data.nodes, function (d) {
                return d.id
            })
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )

        nodes.selectAll("circle")
            .data(d => [d])
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "circle")
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("r", 40)

        simulation
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .on("tick", tick)

        simulation
            .force("link")
            .links(data.links)

        function tick() {
            links.attr("d", function (d) {
                var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
                    dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
                    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
            })

            nodes
                .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        }
```

```css
    .path {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .nodes {
        fill: whitesmoke;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <!-- D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add only the nodes referenced in the links, you need to build a set and then filter the nodes on it. At the moment you seem to be adding in some node(s) twice over;

PS. It turns out your extra node is because you initialised nodes as [{}] i.e. you had an empty object {} already declared in the array and then you added to that. Still, this suggestion is more scalable as you only have to loop round the links and nodes once each rather than nest them.

You'll also find the i = i + 1 in the original code made things dependent on link order (try moving the A-B link to the end of the link array and see what happens - I reckon it'll find A, increase i to 1 (B), and then the next iteration of the node loop will move it to 2 (C) and you'll never pick B up)

```js
        var width = window.innerWidth,
            height = window.innerHeight;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        ////////////////////////
        // outer force layout
        
        var unfilteredData = {
            "nodes": [{
                "id": "A",
            },
            {
                "id": "B",
            },
            {
                "id": "C",
            },
            {
                "id": "D",
            },
            {
                "id": "E",
            }],
            "links": [{
                "source": "A",
                "target": "B"
            },
            {
                "source": "B",
                "target": "C"
            },
            {
                "source": "C",
                "target": "A"
            }]
        }

        let data = {
            "nodes":[{}],
            "links":[{}],
        }

        data.links = unfilteredData.links

        // THESE LINES
        nodeSet = new Set();
        unfilteredData.links.forEach (function (link) {
            nodeSet.add (link.source);
            nodeSet.add (link.target);
        });
        data.nodes = unfilteredData.nodes.filter (function (node) {
            return nodeSet.has (node.id);
        });

      

        console.table(data.nodes)

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id
            }).distance(250))

        linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkscontainer")
        nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")


        links = linksContainer.selectAll(".path")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "path")
            .attr("fill", "transparent")

        nodes = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
            .data(data.nodes, function (d) {
                return d.id
            })
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )

        nodes.selectAll("circle")
            .data(d => [d])
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "circle")
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("r", 40)

        simulation
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .on("tick", tick)

        simulation
            .force("link")
            .links(data.links)

        function tick() {
            links.attr("d", function (d) {
                var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
                    dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
                    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
            })

            nodes
                .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        }
```

```css
    .path {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .nodes {
        fill: whitesmoke;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <!-- D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of each node that does not have a link (`id`) to 'hidden':

```js
nodes.style("visibility", (d) => d.id ? "visible" : "hidden");
```

---

```js
var width = window.innerWidth,
height = window.innerHeight;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
        svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
    }))
    .append("g")

var unfilteredData = {"nodes": [{"id": "A", }, {"id": "B", }, {"id": "C", }, {"id": "D", }, {"id": "E", }], "links": [{"source": "A", "target": "B"}, {"source": "B", "target": "C"}, {"source": "C", "target": "A"}] }

let data = {
    "nodes":[{}],
    "links":[{}],
}

data.links = unfilteredData.links

for (let i = 0; i < unfilteredData.nodes.length; i++) {
    unfilteredData.links.forEach( function(li) {
        if (unfilteredData.nodes[i].id == li.source || unfilteredData.nodes[i].id == li.target ) {
            data.nodes.push(unfilteredData.nodes[i])
            i = i+1
        }
    })
}

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
        return d.id
    }).distance(250))

linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkscontainer")
nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")


links = linksContainer.selectAll(".path")
    .data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "path")
    .attr("fill", "transparent")

nodes = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(data.nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id
    })
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragStarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragEnded)
    )

nodes.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => [d])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .style("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("r", 40)
    
nodes.style("visibility", (d) => d.id ? "visible" : "hidden");

simulation
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", tick)

simulation
    .force("link")
    .links(data.links)

function tick() {
    links.attr("d", function (d) {
        var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
            dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    })

    nodes
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
}

function dragStarted(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(event, d) {
    d.fx = event.x;
    d.fy = event.y;
}

function dragEnded(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.path {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.nodes {
    fill: whitesmoke;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
<!-- D3 -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```